# ESP8266 + NeoPixel - Cannot set pixel color, I got "Exception 29: StoreProhibited"

Tags: esp8266, rgb-led, neopixel

I'm trying to use NeoPixel on the ESP8266.
I made simple test put all required code into `setup()` and `loop()` methods. Then, to keep everything in order I create a class `LedModule` which handle the led strip state, changes, etc.

Here some parts of my class

```
LedModule::LedModule(unsigned int numOfPixels, uint8_t dataPin)
{
    // When we setup the NeoPixel library, we tell it how many pixels, and which pin to use to send signals.
    // Note that for older NeoPixel strips you might need to change the third parameter--see the strandtest
    // example for more information on possible values.
    pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(numOfPixels, dataPin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);


    mState = LED_MODULE_STATE_IDLE;
    mIsLedStripOn = false;
}

...

// The method to set all leds of the strip to the same color
void LedModule::turnAllNeoPixelsTo(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue)
{
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < getLedCount(); i++)
    {
        // Avoid to light up the middle leds
        if (i < 5 || i > 9)
        {
            pixels.setPixelColor(i, red, green, blue);
        }
        else{
            pixels.setPixelColor(i, 0,0,0); // off
        }
    }
    pixels.show(); // This sends the updated pixel color to the hardware.
    mIsLedStripOn = true;
}
```

After this changes, when I call the method above, I got the exception:

```
Exception 29: StoreProhibited: A store referenced a page mapped with an attribute that does not permit stores
Decoding 15 results
0x4020ddbd: ieee80211_send_mgmt at ?? line ?
0x4020db5f: ieee80211_send_mgmt at ?? line ?
0x40102864: trc_NeedRTS at ?? line ?
0x4020fe6d: ieee80211_sta_new_state at ?? line ?
0x402101ab: ieee80211_sta_new_state at ?? line ?
0x4021060f: sta_input at ?? line ?
0x402109cb: ieee80211_parse_wmeparams at ?? line ?
0x402103ab: sta_input at ?? line ?
0x40204ce3: pp_tx_idle_timeout at ?? line ?
0x40204607: ppPeocessRxPktHdr at ?? line ?
```

It seems to crash during the `pixels.setPixelColor(i, red, green, blue);` method.

Comment: What is `pixels`?

Comment: instance of Adafruit_NeoPixel library object. I updated the class code above.

Comment: I don't like your method of constructing. I think you need a new in there and make it a pointer

Comment: I used the sample coming from the library. You can find it here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/arduino-library

Comment: That is completely different, sorry.

Comment: `pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(...) `creates a local variable (an rvalue) then copies it to the class member. If `Adafruit_NeoPixel` does not have a proper `operator=` problems may arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "constructor" isn't doing what you think.

In the example you point to you have, efectively:

```
Class object = Class(parameters);
```

Whereas in your code you have:

```
Class object;

object = Class(parameters);
```

In the first form it results in a new `object` constructed at declaration time. In the second it first creates a new "empty" object and then at a later date tries to copy a newly constructed object into it - which may be failing if the class doesn't support copying.

Instead you should be working with `new` and pointers.

In your class definition you create a pointer to your Adafruit class:

```
private:
    Adafruit_NeoPixel *pixels;
```

Then you create a `new` object pointing to it:

```
pixels = new Adafruit_NeoPixel(numOfPixels, dataPin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
```

Accessing it is then done with `->` instead of `.`:

```
pixels->setPixelColor(i, red, green, blue);
```

Comment: Another option (to avoid `new`) would be to use the initializer list: `LedModule::LedModule(unsigned int numOfPixels, uint8_t dataPin) : pixels(numOfPixels, dataPin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800) {...}`

Comment: Yeah, I thought of suggesting that, but it can get a bit awkward with the Arduino API and the order things get initialized. I find it's best in general to do things in begin() rather than with constructors. Besides, there's no harm in using new in this situation.

Comment: Another option would be to extend the NeoPixel class creating a child class that adds more functions to it.